# Efficiently combine CSS Selectors for multiple types in child element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

If I want to style all of the `<input type="submit"/>` within the `<div class="control-group control-connected">` in`<form>`s, I can apply this type of selector:

```
form div.control-group.control-connected input[type=submit]{}
```

However, let's say I want to also style the `<button>` elements within those types of divs as well.

Is there a more efficient way than doing this?

```
form div.control-group.control-connected input[type=submit],form div.control-group.control-connected button
```

That implementation seems rather wordy, and also redundant, shouldn't I be able to do something like this?

```
form div.control-group.control-connected (input[type=submit], button)
```

Comment: Not in raw CSS.  If you use something like LESS there is probably an easier pattern to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you'd have to use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) if you wanted to use a more compact syntax.

Comment: I actually happen to be using Less, how would I achieve it using that specific preprocessor?

Comment: See http://lesscss.org/#-nested-rules (although note I haven't actually used LESS - I just happened to be reading the site the other day).

Answer (score 2):

The shorter way is to use class names for elements that share a common style.

Comment: True, but it is more semantic to have only the `<div>` styled, and all the elements within it styled accordingly. I guess CSS isn't meeting my standards.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

http://sass-lang.com/

sass lang will clean your css

Answer (score 0):

If you need the specificity, go with the notation you mentioned.
There's currently no widespread support for native CSS mixins to achieve what you want.

If you're interested in developer productivity with CSS, I recommend you give SASS a try:
http://sass-lang.com/

Answer (score 0):

Until we get support for nesting in CSS, you'll either have to write it out like that, or use a preprocessor of some sort, such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), to allow you to write stylesheets that are easier to read.

***Note:** LESS, SASS, and other variants require you to convert from the input format (LESS, SASS, etc) to CSS before displaying on a website. There are automatic methods of doing this (both server-side and client-side).*

### Example in LESS

```
form div.control-group.control-connected {
 input[type=submit], button {
  /* Styles here */
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In native CSS the solution would be:

1: add an ID attribute to the element `div.control-group.control-connected`.

```
#control-connected input[type=submit],
#control-connected button {
    /* css */
}
```

2: add a common class name to the elements.

```
.fancy-style {
    /* css */
}
```

The non-native CSS solutions would be [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).